# UITextField possibly being released too soon and I cannot figure out where and why

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

Here are the areas of concern in my class:

`.h`

```
@interface TimerViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UITextField *hourField,*minuteField;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *hourField,*minuteField;

@end
```

`.m`

```
@implementation TimerViewController
@synthesize hourField,minuteField;

@end
```

My issue is that I can use the text fields multiple times (retrieve and set properties) before the app crashes with this log:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
'-[__NSCFString setText:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e1dafa0'
```

This happens when the code `[self.hourField setText:@"5"];` is run. It can also happen when checking if `[self.hourField isFirstResponder]` with the same type of log.

The console sees the text field as a `__NSCFString` which leads me to think it may have been released?

Runs with ARC, and I'm always using synthesised accessors. Never had this issue before and can't see where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be a confusion with how you declared the variables. You do not need the @synthesize statement anymore and and normally you would want to have your private iVars have a different spelling than your property declarations. To see if this is the problem remove both your @property declaration and your @synthesize and access hourField simply as [hourField setText:@"5"]; . Another way would be to remove the @synthesize and the iVar declarations altogether.

Other I would check are whether the IBOutlet is connected to the right item in your .xib or storyboard.

Comment: I removed the iVar declarations and kept the @property declarations and synthesizers. It's definitely connected to the outlet as I'm able to make use of the text fields a couple of times. Still having the same problem though. Any more ideas?

Comment: I think I agree with you that its ARC cleaning it up underneath you. Maybe you can try turning ARC off for that file and see if that changes anything. You can do this by adding "-fno-objc-arc" as a flag to the file under your target -> build phases -> Compile sources. This is kind of a shot in the dark though but it may work. Also change the property to (retain, nonatomic)

Comment: Also did you remove the @synthesize? That is implied now

Comment: Yeah, still the same result. I don't want to resort to having a non-ARC view controller in my otherwise ARC project. I think I'll try creating a new view controller and add everything back in. Worth a shot.

Comment: Didn't work, same problem. Going out my mind here. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Is it in anyway connected to a view that gets released or removed from the superview?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20273/discussion-between-sooper-and-rooster117)